# How to load .so file inside linux kernel file

Tags: android, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, .so

I am trying to build my custom library in form of .so file in android kernel and then load that library in one of the kernel config files and use library functions.

I am unable to do it. I an not able to include dlfcn header inside the kernel config file to load my .so.

Can anybody help and guide me how to do this!!

Comment: No, you can't. Just as simple as you may expect.

Comment: Why is it so, is it some kind of limitation for kernel files?

Comment: .so files are userspace library. Kernel will be in another memory space. you can't link this between two.